# Type Unicode code points into Python CLI

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.2

Consider that Python will all one to type the name 'Jânis' into the Python CLI, if it is known that the 'â' character is hex "E2" in CP-1252:

```
>>> 'J\xe2nis'
'Jânis'
```

**How might one type that name into the Python CLI if the Unicode code point is known, but not the CP-1252 point?** In fact, the code point in question is`U+00E2`. Also, the UTF-8 encoded character is `%C3 %A2`, is there any way to type that into the Python CLI if only that is known?

I am using Python 3.2 on Kubuntu Linux 12.10.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `'J\u00e2nis'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unicode escape sequence (`\unnnn`):

```
>>> 'J\u00e2nis'
'Jânis'
```

If you know utf-8, use [`bytes.decode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) (`utf-8` is default encoding in Python 3.x, so it is optional):

```
>>> b'J\xc3\xa2nis'.decode('utf-8')
'Jânis'
```

If you have `%C3%A2`, use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote('J%c3%a2nis', encoding='utf-8')
'Jânis'
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! Would you by chance have any idea what to do if we have only the UTF-8 code points?